# Passing javascript via browser URL field

Tags: javascript, variables, url, browser

like the title states... is there a way to pass javascript via a browser url field.

For example, if I had a function that opened or closed tabs but i wanted to type in the browser the url + function so that on page load the tabs would be opened (or closed)

mydomain.com?windows.open=true (something like that) Is this possible.

Thank you in advanced for your time and responses, they are all very much appreciated.

Comment: Passing JavaScript is a bad idea. TALK ABOUT XSS HOLE! Bad bad bad idea. If you want to send a key to say do X, than querystring parameters are fine. Don't take X and eval it to a script.

Comment: Yes this is possible but is a terrible security hole. Instead, consider passing in a single number which can be used to trigger a set of predefined, safe functions.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I'll take this information with great consideration.

Comment: if you don't need security on the site because the site is just a regular html site, eval(location.hash.slice(1)); would do the trick and would be safer than using GET parameters.

Comment: I think your approach is totally fine, but instead you would call `mydomain.com?windowsopen=true`, and the whole javascript resides in the html page (index.html or default.aspx for example). You execute the javascript if the query string `windowsopen` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use:

1. Pass parameters in a query string, where the next page reads the query string and does something based on it
2. Use one of the many JavaScript libraries or frameworks that allow you to map a hash in the URL to a function in JavaScript (e.g. the BackboneJS router, for example).

The #2 solution is probably the more modern approach.

```
http://mydomain.com/some/page#tabs/open
```

And on that page is some JavaScript that allows you to bind a function to that pattern in the hash. [Sammy.js](https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/) is another one that comes to mind.

```
$.sammy(function() {
    this.get("#/tabs/open", function() {
        // do something with jQuery to make sure tabs are open
    });
});
```